# Label doesn't properly focus a ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, focus

In order to use accelerator keys in a WPF window, you must use a `Label` control. Specify the control to focus in its `Target` property and prefix the hotkey with `_`. This works for `TextBox` controls but not so much for `ListBox`. Instead of focusing the "focused" item, the list box control itself is focused. Pressing the arrow keys then does unpredictable things. Completely unusable like this. Apparently this issue exists [for ten years](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0ccb2b8-a187-4c3b-9b08-5bfc5d50ee1f/labels-target-doesnt-work-properly-for-listbox?forum=wpf) now.

Here's some demo code:

```
<Label Content="_List:" Target="{Binding ElementName=myList}"/>
<ListBox Name="myList" Items="..."/>
<Button Content="OK"/>
```

You need to put some items in the list first, then select the second one. Click the button only to focus it. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to focus the list.

Should I start messing with the `ListBox`'s `GotFocus` event to fix the focus? Or is there a proper solution to this? Did I miss some exotic property to set to make it right?

Comment: Isn't the [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0ccb2b8-a187-4c3b-9b08-5bfc5d50ee1f/labels-target-doesnt-work-properly-for-listbox?forum=wpf#091e3c6a-3e98-46cc-ac54-359c91343b99) mentioned in the link good enough?

Comment: The answer was posted after this question. And no, it doesn't work, and likely will not work, so it's not good enough.

Comment: So I probably don't understand the question then, because I tried the solution in the link and it seemed to work for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem. It does not involve any per-control customisations. All necessary events are automatically attached to all `ListBox` controls per a default style.

I'm handling the `GotKeyboardFocus` event for all `ListBox` controls to check whether the focus really belongs to someone else than the `ListBox` itself. If an item is selected, it will be focused. If not and there is at least one item in the list, the first item will be focused. This would also implicitly select it (which is wrong) so that is fixed, too.

This isn't an exact replication of the native Windows behaviour because it doesn't retain the focused item when the focus was on another control. Windows Forms' `ListBox` distinguishes between one or more selected items and one focused item. Each is properly tracked and remembered. WPF's `ListBox` doesn't seem to care about item focus (obviously, or this whole sad solution wouldn't be necessary) so assumptions have to be made.

This works well enough in my application to not annoy me from a user perspective. Tabbing through controls in both directions works without a problem.

The attached property is implemented in the `ListBoxExtensions` class (`ListBoxExtensions.cs`):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Unclassified.UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides extension methods for WPF ListBox controls.
    /// </summary>
    // Type name used in XAML
    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true, ApplyToMembers = false, Feature = "renaming")]
    public static class ListBoxExtensions
    {
        #region ListBox fix focus attached property

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the FixFocus XAML attached property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FixFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            name: "FixFocus",
            propertyType: typeof(bool),
            ownerType: typeof(ListBoxExtensions),
            defaultMetadata: new PropertyMetadata(OnFixFocusChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the FixFocus XAML attached property from the specified DependencyObject.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object from which to read the property value.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool GetFixFocus(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(FixFocusProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of the FixFocus XAML attached property on the specified DependencyObject.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The target object on which to set the FixFocus XAML attached property.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The property value to set.</param>
        public static void SetFixFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(FixFocusProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnFixFocusChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (obj is ListBox && args != null)
            {
                if ((bool)args.NewValue)
                {
                    ((ListBox)obj).GotKeyboardFocus += ListBox_GotKeyboardFocus;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((ListBox)obj).GotKeyboardFocus -= ListBox_GotKeyboardFocus;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ListBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var listBox = sender as ListBox;
            if (listBox?.IsKeyboardFocused == true)
            {
                // ListBox has KeyboardFocus, it really should be on an item instead to fix keyboard navigation
                if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    // Focus the selected item
                    (listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as UIElement)?.Focus();
                }
                else if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Focus the first item. This implicitly selects it. Clear selection afterwards.
                    (listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as UIElement)?.Focus();
                    listBox.SelectedItem = null;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion ListBox fix focus attached property
    }
}
```

Add this to a `ResourceDictionary` referenced from `App.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Unclassified.UI"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="ListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
        <Setter Property="ui:ListBoxExtensions.FixFocus" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```